# How to pass parameters bw two windows in pyqt5?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I am working on a password manager gui app. Using Qtdesigner I created a main window where I asked for username and password from user. and a dialog window where display the user their username and passwords for different apps and websites. I also called that dialog window from my main window so that when user press login button then if their login credential is correct , the dialog window will appear.

**Now what I want is that when dialog window appears,after clicking push button it should show all data of the user which is stored in a table with that username(like if username is alex then a table with name alex is there in db with username and passwords of different apps/websites).**

*Hope my question is understandable enough to be answered. I can further clarify if anyone interested to answer.*

MY mainwindow file------>

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'main.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.4
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sqlite3
from main2 import Ui_Dialog

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def openwindow(self):
            self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
            
            self.ui = Ui_Dialog() 
            self.ui.setupUi(self.window) 
            self.window.show() 
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(553, 400)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(553, 400))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(553, 400))
        MainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color:\"PowderBlue\"")
       
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
       
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-1, -5, 561, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Dosis ExtraBold")
        font.setPointSize(30)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(87, 8, 97);")
        self.label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.label.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.label.setLineWidth(7)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        
        
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(28, 120, 511, 261))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(176, 224, 230);\n"
"")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
       
       
        self.username = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.username.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(224, 0, 261, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe Print")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.username.setFont(font)
        self.username.setStyleSheet("border :2px solid purple ;\n"
"background-color:PowderBlue;\n"
"border-radius:5px;\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.username.setText("")
        self.username.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Normal)
        self.username.setPlaceholderText("master user")
        self.username.setClearButtonEnabled(False)
        self.username.setObjectName("username")
       
       
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(442, 7, 41, 31))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("image: url(:/user.png);\n"
"background-color:PowderBlue")
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
       
       
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(450, 69, 31, 31))
        self.label_3.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("image: url(:/key.png);\n"
"background-color:PowderBlue")
        self.label_3.setText("")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
       
       
        self.password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.password.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(225, 65, 261, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe Print")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.password.setFont(font)
        self.password.setPlaceholderText("master password")
        self.password.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.DefaultContextMenu)
        self.password.setStyleSheet("border :2px solid purple ;\n"
                                    "border-radius:5px;")

        self.password.setText("")
        self.password.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.password.setPlaceholderText("")
        self.password.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.password.setObjectName("password")
       
       
        self.login_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame,clicked=lambda:self.log_in())
        self.login_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 130, 41, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Comic Sans MS")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.login_button.setFont(font)
        self.login_button.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.login_button.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.login_button.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.login_button.setStyleSheet("image: url(:/login.png);")
        self.login_button.setText("")
        self.login_button.setFlat(True)
        self.login_button.setObjectName("login_button")
        
        
        self.signup_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame,clicked=lambda:self.sign_up())
        self.signup_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(388, 130, 41, 31))
        self.signup_button.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.signup_button.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.signup_button.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.signup_button.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.signup_button.setStyleSheet("image: url(:/user (2).png);")
        self.signup_button.setText("")
        self.signup_button.setFlat(True)
        self.signup_button.setObjectName("signup_button")
        
        
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(25, 7, 141, 141))
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("image: url(:/team.png);")
        self.label_4.setText("")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        
        
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(17, 135, 171, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Forte")
        font.setPointSize(22)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(5, 22, 127);")
        self.label_5.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.label_5.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.label_5.setLineWidth(7)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
       
       
        self.error_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.error_lbl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230,165,251,50))
        #self.error_lbl.textFormat.RichText()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Roboto Black")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(65)
        self.error_lbl.setFont(font)
        self.error_lbl.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255,0,0);")
        self.error_lbl.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.error_lbl.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.error_lbl.setLineWidth(1)
        self.error_lbl.setObjectName("error_lbl")
       
       
       
       
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame)
        self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-17, 190, 20, 61))
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        
        
        self.line_5 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame)
        self.line_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, -20, 20, 221))
        self.line_5.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line_5.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_5.setObjectName("line_5")
       
       
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(349, 231, 41, 31))
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("image: url(:/copyright.png);")
        self.label_6.setText("")
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        
        
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 234, 111, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Comic Sans MS")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.password.raise_()
        self.username.raise_()
        self.label_2.raise_()
        self.label_3.raise_()
        self.login_button.raise_()
        self.signup_button.raise_()
        self.label_4.raise_()
        self.label_5.raise_()
        self.error_lbl.raise_()
        self.line_2.raise_()
        self.line_5.raise_()
        self.label_6.raise_()
        self.label_7.raise_()
       
       
        self.info_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.info_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 0, 41, 23))
        self.info_button.setStyleSheet("image: url(:/information-button.png);")
        self.info_button.setText("")
        self.info_button.setFlat(True)
        self.info_button.setObjectName("info_button")
       
       
        self.line_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 101, 20, 271))
        self.line_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_3.setObjectName("line_3")
       
       
        self.line_6 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 101, 21, 271))
        self.line_6.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line_6.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_6.setObjectName("line_6")
       
       
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(334, 0, 81, 61))
        self.label_8.setStyleSheet("image: url(:/password.png);")
        self.label_8.setText("")
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.line_8 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(19, 90, 511, 20))
        self.line_8.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_8.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_8.setObjectName("line_8")
       
       
        self.line_4 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(19, 364, 361, 16))
        self.line_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_4.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_4.setObjectName("line_4")
        
        
        self.line_7 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(513, 364, 16, 16))
        self.line_7.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_7.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_7.setObjectName("line_7")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 553, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def log_in(self):
                        
        conn = sqlite3.connect("master.db")
        cur = conn.cursor()

        user = self.username.text()
        password = self.password.text()
        print(user)
        print(password)
        if user=="" or password=="" :  
                
                self.error_lbl.setText(  "materuser & masterpassword\nrequired !") 
                
        else:           
                cur.execute("SELECT rowid , *FROM master_database WHERE master_users = ?", (user,))
                
                c=cur.fetchone()
                conn.commit()
                conn.close()

                if c==None:
                
                
                 self.error_lbl.setText( f"No data for {user}\nKindly register for new user !" )
                
                                                        
                else:
                        
                        if c[2] == password:
                        
                         
                                #self.error_lbl.setText("Successfully verified.\nClick to Login")
                                self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
                                self.ui = Ui_Dialog() 
                                self.ui.setupUi(self.window) 
                                self.window.show() 
                        
                        else:
                        
                         self.error_lbl.setText("Incorrect Password !" )  



if __name__ == "__main__":
        import sys
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My Dialog window file------->'

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'main2.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.4
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.



from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sqlite3

class Ui_Dialog(object):

    def loaddata(self):
        connection = sqlite3.connect('master.db')
        query = "SELECT * FROM a"
        
        c = connection.execute(query)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
         
        
        for row_number , row_data in enumerate(c):
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
            for column_number ,data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number,column_number,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
        
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
   
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(553, 424)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        Dialog.setFont(font)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color: PowderBlue;bn  ")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 112, 151, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Raleway Black")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(225, 112, 111, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Raleway Black")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(396, 112, 121, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Raleway Black")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(Dialog)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 150, 531, 271))
        self.tableWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(531, 271))
        self.tableWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(531, 271))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Source Sans Pro SemiBold")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.tableWidget.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(73, 6, 127);")
        self.tableWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.tableWidget.setGridStyle(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(10)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(177)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog,clicked=lambda:self.loaddata())
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 30, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "APP/WEBSITE"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "USERNAME"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PASSWORD"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QStackedWidget.html#detailed-description) to switch between pages.

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
stackedwidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
page1 = PageOneClass()
page2 = PageTwoClass()
stackedwidget.addWidget(page1)
stackedwidget.addWidget(page2)

stackedwidget.show()
app.exec_()
```

This will let you switch between pages without running another file. Now to get values from one page to another, use inheritance.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.user = self.username.text()
        self password = self.password.text()  #Now the user, password can be accessed using the class name. dont forget to add self.
  
  
class DialogWindow(MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, MainWindow):
        super(DialogWindow, self).__init__()
        usernamefrompage1 = MainWindow.user
        passwordfrompage1 = MainWindow.password

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

stackedwidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
mainwindow_instance = MainWindow()
dialogwindow_instance = DialogWindow(mainwindow_instance)  
#we are passing the mainwindow instance to the dialog window instance, this will let us use all the methods and attributes of the mainwindow.

stackedwidget.addWidget(mainwindow_instance)
stackedwidget.addWidget(dialogwindow_instance)
stackedwidget.setCurrentWidget(mainwindow_instance)

stackedwidget.show()
app.exec_()
```